# Execution Errors after perl update on arch linux

Tags: arch-linux, perl

I updated perl to "perl-5.26.0-1-x86_64" through "pacman -Syu" which is what I suspect to be the cause of the execution errors that I now encounter:
When trying to start vim:

```
if_perl.c: loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb80080, needed 0xde00080)
```

When trying to download cpanm modules:

```
loadable library and perl binaries are mismatched (got handshake key 0xdb80080, needed 0xde00080)
```

After some research I found this:
https://lists.archlinux.org/pipermail/arch-dev-public/2014-June/026359.html

which leads to "recompile non-pure perl-modules". I have generated such lists. How can I get my applications back running?

Info:

pacman is version 5.0.1 - libalpmv10.0.1

Linux localhost 4.10.13-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Remove or rebuild all the perl modules that you installed manually or from the AUR.

Comment: How can I rebuild these modules? Normally i would use perl -MCPAN -e shell to install im unable to find something on rebuilding / recompiling.

Comment: Remove them, then. Don't mix pacman-managed files with self-installed ones, it just breaks things.

Comment: `cpanm` has a `--reinstall` option; see also `local::lib` to stash whatever not-vendor-supplied module you have into their own directory so at least they're not mixed up with the vendor space.

Comment: I had the same issue when trying to start vim, but did not have issues with cpan modules (nor had I ever installed any manually or via AUR package). My problem was a very old version of the perl-support vim plugin. Removing it and/or upgrading it both fixed the issue.

Answer (score -1):

Two things are likely:

1. Your mirror is out of sync or partially synced.
   In this case you should go here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Mirrors
   Find a recently synced mirror and use that to update your machine.
2. Arch's packages are out of sync. You will need to downgrade versions back to what was working before. The archives are here: https://archive.archlinux.org/